# How can I read/check the assembly generated from compiling shader code?

Tags: assembly, glsl, shader, hlsl, directx-10

How can I check the generated assembly from compiling a HLSL shader in DX10, for example?

I'm looking for some output like shown in Humus' presentation here (http://www.humus.name/Articles/Persson_LowLevelThinking.pdf), so I can see what instructions are generated by my shader programs.

Comment: See here: http://blog.vertexwahn.de/Wordpress/?p=188. Should work similar for DX10.

Answer (score 0):

There's a open source project [Shader Playground](https://github.com/tgjones/shader-playground) for exploring shader compilers.

You can visit the https://shader-playground.timjones.io website. It can help you to see what instructions are generated by your shader programs.